# Create LAS Dataset in ArcGIS

Tags: arcmap, las

I created a LAS Dataset out of my 1000 LAS-Files (regular grids) with the purpose of converting the LAS Dataset to a Raster later on.

But the problem is: my LAS-Files are overlapped on the borders and I want the LAS Dataset to maintain all the values at the borders so I can average them later on using "LAS Dataset to Raster". Unfortunately my created LAS Dataset only chose one value to keep.

Anyone has an idea of how to keep overlapped values on the LAS Dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It is only a display problem. When I use my created LAS Dataset to convert it to Raster, it recognized all values at the borders and averaged them as I wanted.